# Redux Persist specific Reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux

I would like to persist specifically my user reducer, and not my job search reducer. However, I am not sure how to setup my store accordingly with this.

Please see what I currently have:

```
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import userReducer from "./userSlice";
import jobsearchSlice from './jobsearchSlice'

import {
  persistStore,
  persistReducer,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  version: 1,
  storage,
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({ user: userReducer,
                                      jobsearch: jobsearchSlice
                                    });  //maybe delete?

                                    
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer, 
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }),
});

export let persistor = persistStore(store);
```

I would expect the user reducer to not persist, and be refreshed on each instance, whilst the user will persist during the login. Hope that makes sense.

What is the best manner to decouple this and make it as above?

https://gyazo.com/2a86fa0c55a671148dc6098f5dfa0f7a

Answer (score 2):

Try to pass "whitelist: ['your-specific-reducer-her']," in your persistConfig

This makes to your persist setup allow only the reducers that match name in the whitelist array.

Alternatively, you can pass "blacklist" instead, this inverts the list to allow only reducers that doesn't match name in the blacklist array.

```
const persistConfig = {
      key: "root",
      version: 1,
      whitelist: ["your-reducer-name-here"]
      storage,
 };
```